# How can I repair a handheld shower head hose that burst?

Tags: plumbing, shower, bathtub, hose

I'm looking to fix a handheld shower head tube that burst. There is no easy access to replace the entire hose. Luckily the burst happened at the head. I'm hoping that there's a way to cut the hose and reattach the connector.

Does anyone know how to remove the connector from the hose and if there's a tool to reattach it? Or is there a better way to fix the hose?

Thanks!

[image: hand held shower head]
[image: burst hose]
[image: connector]

Comment: Face getting to the other end, however "not-easy" that may be, as complete replacement is usually the only practical way to fix these.

Comment: Assuming "no easy access" means this tub is completely tiled in.   Have you considered breaking through the ceiling below or the wall in the adjacent room?  Could you perhaps even then install an access door at the end of the job?  You'll need to do this eventually, even if you can hack together a repair to this hose.

Comment: Replacement, not repair.

Answer (score 3):

As commented I think you'll need to replace the whole hose.

It *may* be worth trying to pry the white plastic part back from the brass part (or think of it as prying the brass part and hose out of the white part) which appears as if it might then let you remove the hose from the brass part, shorten the tube, with the white part over it, insert the brass part in the tube, then push the white part back over the join. I don't *kno*w that works, but it looks like it MIGHT be the way this one works, if there's no additional crimp inside the white part that will be difficult to replicate at home.

Assuming it even works, there's still a large possibility that the tube is fatigued and will just repeat the previous failure in a short time.

Comment: Or that the newly hand-assembled (instead of machine assembled) junction will simply leak. At a minimum, it's worth a shot - at best it'll work for another 5 years; at worst it won't be any more broken than it already is.